# EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams cause issue with LINQ queries e.g Where, FirstOrDefault

Tags: eventstoredb

**EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams cause issue with LINQ queries e.g `Where, FirstOrDefault`**
We have made a seperate class Library project (net standard 2.1) and install

1. `EventStore.Client - 20.10.0`
2. `EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams  - 20.10.0`
   Then we add reference of that class library project into our `netCore3.1webApi`. After adding reference we start receiving this error
   [image]

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Make a seperate class library project targeting netStandard2.1.
2. Install
   i.  `EventStore.Client - 20.10.0`
   ii. `EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams  - 20.10.0` in class library project
3. Then make a `netCore3.1webApi` project in the same solution and make it a simple C.R.U.D type project.
4. When you add refernce of class Library project in netCore3.1webApi, you will start receiving errors as screenshot attached above

**Expected behavior**
EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams have System.Linq.Async.dll. Either this should be removed or make its namespace seperate as it is conflicting with LINQ methods which causes error

**Actual behavior**
System.Linq.Async.dll conflicts with basic Linq Queries which makes compiler difficult to decide which method we are refering

**Config/Logs/Screenshots**
`_context.TableName.Where(x=>x.Name="test");` With this line the error comes:
[image]

**EventStore details**

- EventStore server version: 20.10.0
- Operating system: Windows 10
- EventStore client version (if applicable):
- 1. `EventStore.Client - 20.10.0`
- 2. `EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams  - 20.10.0`

Comment: Do you have a repro repository? We have lots of applications, which use the gRPC .NET client, and, of course, have LINQ queries. Never had any issues with it.